# Using std::initializer_list to create a tree?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

What I have is something like:

```
struct ExprTreeNode {
   char c;
   std::vector< int > i;
};

ExprTreeNode tn { '+', { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
```

What I want to write is something like:

```
MyTree t1 { '+', { 1, 2, { '*', { 3, 4, 5 } } } };
MyTree t2 { '*', { { '+', { 77, 88, 99, 111 } }, { '-', { 44, 33 } } } };
```

I'm free to define the MyTree class (and possible helper classes) - but it should be something tree-ish - like operator as a TreeNode content and a container (e.g. a std::vector) holding the subnodes.

In C++ is it possible to use such an initializer_list to initialize a tree-like structure?  (If it is possible, a hint how to do this would be nice.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
struct ExprTreeNode {
    bool is_value;
    int i;
    char c;
    std::vector< ExprTreeNode > v;

    ExprTreeNode( int i_ ) : is_value( true ), i( i_ ) {}
    ExprTreeNode( char c_, std::initializer_list< ExprTreeNode > v_ )
      : is_value( false ), c( c_ ), v( v_ ) {}
};

ExprTreeNode tn { '+', { 1, 2, { '*', { 3, 4 } } } };
```

(in practice you might want to combine `i` and `c`)

Here's a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9cIBJ%2416).

---

**Update:** As it was pointed out in another Q/A where I used a similar technique, the above is undefined behaviour as I am using `std::vector<ExprTreeNode>` as a member and at that point, `ExprTreeNode` is not a complete type. The following should fix it:

```
struct ExprTreeNode {
    int value_;
    char op_;
    std::shared_ptr< void > subnodes_;

    ExprTreeNode( int v ) : value_( v ) {}
    ExprTreeNode( char op, std::initializer_list< ExprTreeNode > subnodes );

    void print() const;
};

typedef std::vector< ExprTreeNode > Nodes;

ExprTreeNode::ExprTreeNode( char op, std::initializer_list< ExprTreeNode > l )
  : op_(op), subnodes_(std::make_shared<Nodes>(l))
{}
```

This uses the `shared_ptr` also as a flag for leaf/non-leaf and if you want to use it, you need to cast it first:

```
void ExprTreeNode::print() const
{
   if( !subnodes_ ) {
      std::cout << value_;
   }
   else {
      std::cout << op_ << " ( ";
      for( const auto& e : *std::static_pointer_cast<Nodes>(subnodes_) ) {
         e.print(); std::cout << " ";
      }
      std::cout << ")";
   }
}
```

Here's the updated [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1WXPbx%241).